# Twitter crawling based on hashtag

Tags: python, twitter, web-crawler, data-science, data-analysis

Now am working on twitter crawling. Am using Tweepy library with API Authentication so it provides 150 rows and after it has to wait till 15min to crawl other part so is there any other ideas to avoid these wait time?

Comment: 1. Show code. 2. Do you require tweets as they come in or do you want tweets that were made in the past?

Comment: I want tweets which is tweeted in past